# Prologue is プロローグ or 序章?

Tags: word-choice

For example, in a novel, do we use プロローグ or 序章?

Comment: Um... エピローグ means "epilogue", right?

Answer (score 6):

As a Japanese I think both are ok because プロローグ is already common in many translated books, especially among young people.  In my impression プロローグ gives a modern, western image and 序章 gives a classical, formal and of a long-story image. And I tend to think プロローグ is something extra to main chapters and expect it shorter, on the other hand 序章 is a part of the main chapters.